# Algorithm: Find peak in a circle

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry

Given `n` integers, arranged in a circle, show an efficient algorithm that can find one peak. A peak is a number that is not less than the two numbers next to it.

One way is to go through all the integers and check each one to see whether it is a peak. That yields `O(n)` time. It seems like there should be some way to divide and conquer to be more efficient though.

Comment: Is it necessary to know the location of the peak in the circle, or just the integer value of the peak?

Comment: Both location and integer are needed. Let's assume that the integers are stored as an array `A[1..n]`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867437/algorithm-find-peak-in-a-line

Comment: So a flat line is a peak? 3 3 3 3 3 3 => no element is less than its neighbours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive `O(log n)` algorithm.

Suppose we have an array of numbers, and we know that the middle number of that segment is no smaller than the endpoints:

```
A[i] <= A[m] >= A[j]
```

for i,j indexes into an array, and `m=(i+j)/2`.  Examine the elements midway between the endpoints and the midpoint, i.e. those at indexes `x=(3*i+j)/4` and `y=(i+3*j)/4`.  If `A[x]>=A[m]`, then recurse on the interval `[i,m]`.  If `A[y]>=A[m]`, then recurse on the interval `[m,j]`.  Otherwise, recurse on the interval `[x,y]`.

In every case, we maintain the invariant on the interval above.  Eventually we get to an interval of size 2 which means we've found a peak (which will be `A[m]`).

To convert the circle to an array, take 3 equidistant samples and orient yourself so that the largest (or one tied for the largest) is in the middle of the interval and the other two points are the endpoints.  The running time is `O(log n)` because each interval is half the size of the previous one.

I've glossed over the problem of how to round when computing the indexes, but I think you could work that out successfully.

Answer (score 3):

#### EDIT

Well, Keith Randall proved me wrong. :)

Here's Keith's solution implemented in Python:

```
def findPeak(aBase):
    N = len(aBase)
    def a(i): return aBase[i % N]

    i = 0
    j = N / 3
    k = (2 * N) / 3
    if a(j) >= a(i) and a(j) >= a(k)
        lo, candidate, hi = i, j, k
    elif a(k) >= a(j) and a(k) >= a(i):
        lo, candidate, hi = j, k, i + N
    else:
        lo, candidate, hi = k, i + N, j + N


    # Loop invariants:
    # a(lo) <= a(candidate)
    # a(hi) <= a(candidate)

    while lo < candidate - 1 or candidate < hi - 1:
        checkRight = True
        if lo < candidate - 1:
            mid = (lo + candidate) / 2
            if a(mid) >= a(candidate):
                hi = candidate
                candidate = mid
                checkRight = False
            else:
                lo = mid
        if checkRight and candidate < hi - 1:
            mid = (candidate + hi) / 2
            if a(mid) >= a(candidate):
                lo = candidate
                candidate = mid
            else:
                hi = mid

    return candidate % N
```

Comment: A peak always exists even if we allow duplicate numbers (see definition of a peak.) Also, since the problem asks only to find one peak, it might not be necessary that we always have to examine all the numbers.

Comment: It is not necessary to ALWAYS examine all the numbers but that's not the point of average case algorithmic runtime

Comment: @AK4749 You're missing my point. I was saying that rob mayoff's argument is not sufficient to show that an algorithm better than O(N) doesn't exist.

Comment: @PaulSeangwongree You're right, a peak always exists since it's defined as “not less than”.  Anyway, big-O notation describes the asymptotic upper bound of a function.  I demonstrated that the upper bound on the number of elements you examine is *N*.  So the best possible function runs in O(*N*) time.

Comment: @PaulSeangwongree I understand that you can skip parts of the circle, but I claim that his argument *is* sufficient due to his last paragraph (think 1,2,3,4,5...9,cycle back to 1.)

Comment: @robmayoff When you say "No matter what order you choose to examine the numbers in, there's an arrangement that puts the peak at the last number you examine", you neglect to consider that the order I choose to examine the numbers may depend on the numbers themselves. (If my algorithm had to examine the numbers in **fixed** order, then you would be right.)

Comment: @PaulSeangwongree maybe I'm just not wrapping my head around it correctly, but how can, by having an unknown circle of numbers, you decide *not* to move in a (relatively) linear fashion? For example, you can never jump an arbitrary distance based on your current location because your current provides no information about later numbers. As such, any method would *have* to be O(N), would it not?

Comment: See here for why it might not have to be O(N): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867437/algorithm-find-peak-in-a-line/12867438#12867438

Answer (score 0):

When you say "arranged in a circle", you mean like in a circular linked list or something? From the way you describe the data set, it sounds like these integers are completely unordered, and there's no way to look at N integers and come to any kind of conclusion about any of the others. If that's the case, then the brute-force solution is the only possible one.

Edit:

Well, if you're not concerned with worst-case time, there are slightly more efficient ways to do it. The naive approach would be to look at N<sub>i</sub>, N<sub>i-1</sub>, and N<sub>i+1</sub> to see if Ni is a peak, then repeat, but you can do a little better.

```
While not done
    If N[i] < N[i+1]
        i++
    Else
        If N[i]>N[i-1]
            Done
        Else
            i+=2
```

(Well, not quite that, because you have to deal with the case where N[i]=N[i+1]. But something very similar.)

That will at least keep you from comparing N<sub>i</sub> to N<sub>i+1</sub>, adding 1 to i, and then redundantly comparing N<sub>i</sub> to N<sub>i-1</sub>. It's a distinctly marginal gain, though. You're still marching through the numbers, but there's no way around that; jumping blindly is unhelpful, and there's no way to look ahead without taking just as long as doing the actual work would be.

Comment: This is not true; if you determine that n_i is greater than n_(i+1), you do not need to check n_(i+1). It is possible to not check all numbers.  This does not change that the algorithm will always have a worst case of linear time, however.