# Algorithm: Find peak in a line

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given `n` integers, arranged in a line, show an efficient algorithm that can find one peak. A peak is a number that is not less than the two numbers next to it (or the one number next to it, if it's at the end of the line.)

Comment: do you want the first peak? or the highest peak? Wouldn't the highest peak be just the maximum value?

Comment: @CharlesBretana One peak suffices. Finding the highest peaks takes `O(n)`.

Comment: Why do you post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867018/algorithm-find-peak-in-a-circle) twice?

Comment: @KingsIndian They're quite different. Read carefully.

Comment: Only a slight variation, not different.

Comment: So a flat line is a peak? 3 3 3 3 3 3 => no element is less than its neighbours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `O(log n)` algorithm exists. We use divide-and-conquer.

```
find_peak(lo,hi):
  mid = (lo+hi)/2
  if A[mid] >= A[mid-1], A[mid+1] return mid
  if A[mid] < A[mid-1] 
    return find_peak(lo,mid-1) // a peak must exists in A[1..mid-1]
  if A[mid] < A[mid+1]
    return find_peak(mid+1,hi) // a peak must exists in A[mid+1..hi]
```

Comment: you answer is missing an exit condition. Take the example of an increasing sequence. if lo == hi, return lo :)

Comment: @lcfseth That's true. I guess the idea should be fine though. :)

Comment: This answer does not work. Take the sequence "1 9 3 4 5 5 5", the first test is with the numbers '3 4 5' and the algorithm then chooses the upper half to recurse into. The upper half has no peak. The peak in the lower half is never considered.

Comment: @PaulS. do mean lowest index & highest index of element by lo, hi ? So, we can find middle index and divide the array of n element problem into halfs?